# Можно ли вставить в поле input file картинку с этой же html стр не скачивая ее?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Можно ли вставить в поле input file картинку с этой же html стр не скачивая ее?

Comment: Немного не понятна суть вопроса, Вы хотите что бы пользователь мог выбрать картинку из предзагруженных на сервер или загрузил свою?

Answer (score -1):

Можно, вот пример с вашей аватарокой(если это вы и имели ввиду):

```css
input {
    background-image: url("https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/de6a5e14a6042839e073ac37ccb10928?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG");/*Указываем адрес картинки*/   
    background-repeat: no-repeat; /*Убираем повтор изображения*/   
    background-position: 4px; /*Позиционируем*/   
    outline: none; /*убираем стандартную обводку браузера*/   
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; /*закругляем углы для Mozilla*/  
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; /*закругляем углы для Chrome, Safari*/   
    border-radius: 5px; /*закругляем углы для остальных браузеров*/  
    padding-left: 20px; /*отступ слева от ввода, чтобы текст не был на картинке(выбирать по размеру картинки)*/  
    height: 20px; /*высота строки ввода*/   
    font-size: 13px; /*размер шрифта*/
}
```

```html
<input/>
```

Comment: Думаю вопрос заключается в том, как сделать значение поля input type="file"  картинкой, которая уже есть на странице. Ответ не соответствует вопросу.

Comment: @МихаилЛелякин Возможно, именно по этому я и написал: "если это вы и имели ввиду". Жду пока автор вопроса ответит.